# What do I need to switch power automatically from utility to solar offgrid inverter with no downtime at all during the transfer?

Tags: electrical, home-automation, power-backup, inverter

I want to switch power somewhere where power outage happens frequently from utility to inverter and back and forth kind of like a UPS without giving up on my inverter and what I already have.

Comment: There are inverters that will use the primary input and switch in or out other sources as necessary seamlessly. Trace spring to mind.

Comment: Where are you on this planet? What make and model is your existing inverter?  Why do you need a 0-downtime switching setup? (Most devices any more can deal with a 16-20ms switching delay without any loss of function.)

Comment: Zero downtime??? Most of the switching is break before make.

Comment: What is the calculated power demand you are trying to use the inverter for? Most inverters and ups' only have a 15 or 30 minute supply at 80% of the output. How long are your outages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, typical inverter switch times are fine for most devices.

The only way I know of to literally have NO downtime is dual-conversion, where your inverter is supplying the AC power 100% of the time, and your grid power is converted to DC and fed into the battery / DC input of the inverter.

That has built-in inefficiencies (thus, wasted power), but is "zero-switch" time as there's never a switch on the inverted power, you just go from float-charging the batteries from AC & solar to drawing down the batteries/solar.

Comment: Thank you, I only want to know if there is anyway to switch between grid and inverter without my modem and security dvr going down.